# localStorage event not firing when I run it through console

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a chat application that can communicate through tabs, so I'm using localStorage for that.
Okay, to reproduce the issue:

1. open this url twice, so you have 2 tabs open. https://preview.c9users.io/gorgamite/socket/science.html?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io
2. Type anything into the prompt box, and you'll see it in the other tab. Whats happening is its being set as a localstorage value, and there is a storage event that runs when you enter something into the prompt.
3. Open a new tab, and run this code: `localStorage.setItem("Test", "Hello");`

When you do it through console, the storage event does not fire. It only works if its part of the javascript in a website. How can I change this? Why is it that the storage event doesnt go off when you modify a localStorage value through console?

Here's the code of the website:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id = "thing"></h1>
<script>
localStorage.setItem("Test", prompt("Localstorage value:"));
window.onstorage = function(e){
alert(e.newValue); console.log(e);
document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML += e.newValue;
 };
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question, not on an external site.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay, I posted the code

Comment: must be your browser - works fine in mine

Answer (score 1):

The javascript in your code seems to work as designed, at least in Chrome. I'm guessing you've tried this, but to be sure, I pasted the following in the console of one tab:

```
localStorage.setItem("Test", prompt("Localstorage value:"));
  window.onstorage = function(e){
  alert(e.newValue); console.log(e);
  document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML += e.newValue;
};
```

And verified the test in another tab:

```
localStorage.setItem("Test", "Hello");
```

You may want to check that localStorage is enabled in your browser settings. You can do that in Chrome by navigating to:  [chrome://settings/content](http://chrome://settings/content) then making sure "Allow local data to be set" is selected. Might want to try clearing your cache and cookies as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you do it a tab thats not the website I linked?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

The posted code uses prompt. This is a blocking call. The code does not add  the `storage` event handler until after the storage has been set. So nothing will happen in an open tab by way of response to `storage events` until after the prompt raised during page load is dismissed.

The first time you dismiss a prompt box, it adds an `storage` event handler in that tab only (call it "tab 1").  Now if you enter a value in the other opened tab (call it "tab 2"), the handler in "tab 1" is notified of the update and updates the header in "tab 1".

**After dismissing the prompt for the first time in both tabs that were opened** you can

- reload either tab, enter a value at the prompt and press OK. Nothing happens in the reloaded tab (only partly because it has no `onstorage` handler after the reload). But the other tab *is* notified of the update and runs its `storage` event handler which alerts with the new value.
- open the console in either tab from the same domain, type and enter

  `localStorage.setItem("Test", prompt("Localstorage value:"));`

  and respond to the prompt. Again, the `storage` event handler is not called in the tab that is open, but is called in the other tab.

- open the console in another tab that is not from the same domain, paste some code to set local storage and report it back. Warning: this may corrupt local storage for the domain used if it works. Alternatively take my word for it: the test tabs, "tab1" and "tab2", are not affected.

**Why**

> A `StorageEvent` is sent to a window when a storage area it has access to is changed within the context of another document.
>    *(MDN's [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent))*

To gain access to the same storage, the page where you open the console to set local storage must be [from the same origin and use the same protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) as pages you wish to be notified of the change. To be notified, the `storage` event must be fired in the context of a different document - i.e. on a different page.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? the website functions perfectly fine. In step 3, you open a new tab and set something to localStorage. The event does not fire.

Comment: I investigated the instructions further to see what was going on - please see the reworked answer (tested in Firefox).

Comment: Ah, yes, it only works in other tabs. So is there no way to trigger the event through console on a different tab?

Comment: You can trigger the event through the console on a different tab if and only if that tab is open on a page with the same origin and protocol. That gives it access to the same local storage. Trying it on "about: blank" or an empty new tab etc. will fail. Doing it from the console in a third tab opened on the test page will, of course, work.